# Field that relies on a value of a different field in the same register in DML 1.4

Tags: dml-lang

I have part of a register that looks something like this

```
register CC {
    field CSS @ [6:4] is write {
        method write(uint64 value) {
            if (CC.EN.val == 0b1) {
                log spec_viol: "Command set selection should not " +
                "occur when controller has been enabled.";
                return;
            }
            default(value);
        }
    }
    field EN @ [0];
}
```

How can I ensure that when `CC.EN` is set to 1 (for the first time) by setting the value of the register `CC`, that the spec-viol in `CC.CSS` does not occur?

I tried writing to the register for the first time and the spec-viol was triggered

Comment: According to documentation, "The implementation [of read_register] invokes the `read_field` method of all sub-fields [..] in order from least to most significant bit", so assuming little-endian bitorder I think EN *should* be written before CSS.write?

Comment: Oh nevermind, sloppy reading from my side. The semantics you desire is that the EN value from *before* the write should apply to CSS of the current write. So in your code, the field order means that EN is overwritten before CSS reads it, which is not what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Fields in a register in DML are accessed in order of increasing least significant bit. This means that in your example, the `EN` field will be written *before* the `CCS` field. So to achieve this we must pass the state of `EN` *before* the write to the register. We do this by utilizing the `void *aux` argument in the `write_register` and `write_field` templates:

```
register CC {
    method write_register(uint64 value, uint64 enabled_bytes, void *aux) {
        local bool was_enabled = EN.val;
        default(value, enabled_bytes, &was_enabled);
    }

    field CSS @ [6:4] is write_field {
        method write_field(uint64 value, uint64 enabled_bits, void *aux) {
            if ((this.val & enabled_bits) == (value & enabled_bits))
                return;  // no change, ignore
            if (*cast(aux, *bool)) {
                log spec_viol: "Command set selection should not " +
                "occur when controller has been enabled.";
                return;
            }
            this.val = (this.val & ~enabled_bits) | (value & enabled_bits);
        }
    }

    field EN @ [0];
}
```

Comment: When I try this, it get a compile error since there is no default implementation for `write_field`.

Comment: And how it was updated so that it works.

Comment: Consider adding `assert aux == NULL;` in `write_register`: someone may later add bank-level code that sets `aux` for other purposes, and will then need a reminder to also take this code into account.

Answer (score 1):

Another option that does not rely on order:

```
register CC {
    method write_register(uint64 value, uint64 enabled_bytes, void *aux) {
        if (this.val[EN.msb] && value[EN.msb]) {
            if ((CSS.val & (enabled_bytes[CSS.msb:CSS.lsb])) != (value[CSS.msb : CSS.lsb])) {
                log spec_viol: "%s Command set selection should not " +
                "occur when controller has been enabled.", this.qname;
                value[CSS.msb : CSS.lsb] = CSS.val;
            }

        }
        default(value, enabled_bytes, aux);
    }

    field CSS @ [6:4];
    field EN @ [0] is (write) {
        method write(uint64 value) {
            // Do something...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you could use xor to eliminate one bitslice: `(CCS.val^value) & enabled_bytes[...] != 0`

Answer (score 0):

For completeness I want to present the following anti-pattern that occasionally is seen:

```
register CC {
    session bool was_enabled;

    method write_register(uint64 value, uint64 enabled_bytes, void *aux) {
        was_enabled = EN.val;
        default(value, enabled_bytes, aux);
    }

    field CSS @ [6:4] is write_field {
        method write_field(uint64 value, uint64 enabled_bits, void *aux) {
            if ((this.val & enabled_bits) == (value & enabled_bits))
                return;  // no change, ignore
            if (was_enabled) {
                log spec_viol: "Command set selection should not " +
                "occur when controller has been enabled.";
                return;
            }
            this.val = (this.val & ~enabled_bits) | (value & enabled_bits);
        }
    }

    field EN @ [0];
}
```

This approach may look compelling compared to the `aux` approach for type safety reasons; it avoid the need to fiddle with `void` pointers. However, this approach is problematic both because it allocates permanent storage for a variable that is only used temporarily, and because it is not reentrant (will break if the `write_field` method of some field indirectly triggers another write to CC synchronously). The reentrancy problem can be resolved by restoring the old value through a local variable, but the added type safety is not worth the complexity.